# Create ShapeFile from CSV Using OGR and Python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, csv

I want to convert a CSV file of point coordinates to a ShapeFile using OGR and Python. The example.csv file looks like this:

```
ID,X,Y
1,240007.000,647756.000
2,240008.000,647756.000
3,240009.000,647756.000
4,240020.000,647756.000
5,240021.000,647756.000
6,240022.000,647756.000
7,240023.000,647756.000
8,240024.000,647756.000
9,240025.000,647756.000
10,240026.000,647756.000
```

And I have created an OGR virtual dataset definition file with the *.vrt extension. It looks like this:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="example">
        <SrcDataSource>D:\Temp\GCMRC\003L\example_short.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcLayer>example</SrcLayer>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="X" y="Y"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

I have written a simple Python script that tries to open a dataset from the CSV file, loop over the features (simply to prove they are legit) and then export the points to a ShapeFile. I got this to work on [an example that I found](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/layers.html#read-a-csv-of-coordinates-as-an-ogrvrtlayer), but cannot get it to work on my data posted here.

```
from osgeo import ogr

in_ds = ogr.Open("D:/Temp/example.vrt")
lyr = in_ds.GetLayer('example')
for feat in lyr:
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    print geom.ExportToWkt()

ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile").CopyDataSource(in_ds, "D:/Temp/example.shp")
```

The code crashes on the GetGeometryRef() call. It also produces an empty "line" ShapeFile.

Comment: What does the ogrinfo utility show with `ogrinfo d:/Temp/example.vrt -al` ? And shouldn't you write out the layer "lyr" and not the data source "in_ds"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to user30184! You helped me solve it.

The `SrcLayer` must specify the same name as the CSV file. Here is the correct, working VRT file. The change is on line 4:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="example">
        <SrcDataSource>D:\Temp\example_short.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcLayer>example_short</SrcLayer>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="X" y="Y"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```